# Aggregate array of objects into a single array in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm having few documents which is of the form

```json
{
...id information and so on,
coordinates: [{x, y}]
...few other indexes
}
```

I want to generate an elastic search aggregation which will combine whole coordinates array into a single array. For example

The documents are

```json
[
  {
    ...
    coordinates: [
      {x: 20, y: 30},
      {x: 50, y: 10},
      {x: 40, y: 20}
    ],
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    coordinates: [
      {x: 10, y: 5},
      {x: 20, y: 15},
      {x: 60, y: 90},
      {x: 70, y: 50}
    ],
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    coordinates: [
      {x: 90, y: 20},
      {x: 80, y: 70}
    ],
    ...
  },

]
```

In the output I need to generate something like this using the aggregation

```json
[
  {x: 20, y: 30},
  {x: 50, y: 10},
  {x: 40, y: 20},
  {x: 10, y: 5},
  {x: 20, y: 15},
  {x: 60, y: 90},
  {x: 70, y: 50},
  {x: 90, y: 20},
  {x: 80, y: 70}
]
```

Comment: Is coordinates nested field or simple object field?

Comment: @TusharShahi it's a nested field.